# XNA beginner question about draw method

Tags: xna, draw

I understand that I have to draw everything in draw(), and it's looping continuously.

But I don't want to draw texture again and again, for example I want to create a texture, draw something to texture (not spritebatch). than I will only draw that texture in draw().

Is it possible?
What can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not drawing it again is a performance optimisation. You should only do that if you really *need* to.

If you do need to do this, create a render target, draw your scene to the render target, and then draw your render target to the screen each frame (using `SpriteBatch` makes this easy) instead of your scene.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509265/after-writing-to-a-rendertarget-how-to-efficiently-clone-the-output) about caching drawing using render targets.

Answer (score 4):

You have to draw again and again, as in short, if you dont it wont show. A wise man once wrote in a windows development book

Ask not why the text on your windows has to be constantly drawn, ask why it never used to be in DOS/Unix command line.

If something is placed over the area you're drawing too, and you dont redraw it, it just simply wont be there. You need to keep drawing it for it to be sustained on screen. Its done very quickly and wont hurt anything (especially if you're thinking in terms of background)