# WP7 XNA: Does Draw method

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, draw

sorry for a dumb question. We put every drawing objects in Draw method, does all objects get drawn each time even some of them not changed? Does it need some kind of back buffer and draw at once to reduce flickering? or at least add if-else reduce drawing unchanged objects?

Comment: See answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532620/xna-beginner-question-about-draw-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw is called every frame and yes it will re-draw the entire screen even if an object has not been moved or similar.

Comment: And to add to the answer, XNA handles the double buffering for you